# Edit required/exported variable in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have 2 files, db-config.js & util.js. db-config.js contains:

```
var db = exports.db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    database: dbName,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    port: port
});
```

I want to export the db variable in util.js & edit it there so that any other file trying to access db variable from db-config.js gets the updated variable. What I tried is the code below but didn't work for me. Also all the files get the instance of db variable upon startup, so I want that once the variable gets updated, the updated one is available with all the files.

util.js contains:

```
var db= require('../../db/db-config').db;
db = {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a function that returns db instead of db itself.

```
var getDB = function() { return db; }

exports.getDB = exports.getDB;
```

You will have to make sure that you retrieve db before using it in your other files.

Comment: This one is quite close and making some modifications did the work!

Comment: @Ric what modifications did you do that made it work? I suggest you update your question or even add your own answer if the space is needed to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

what about using config.json instead ?

config.json file will contain same info as what your db-config.js

{
  "dbName":"xx",
  "host":"xxx.com", etc..
}

In your code, you will be

var config = getConfig('../config.json');

var host = config.host
var dbName=config.dbName

etc..

If you db config changes all the time, you can dynamically generate the config.json.

Comment: It definitely works and I am already using a dbConfig.json file to store credentials and if the file doesn't contains any credentials then I go for authentication. But I have over thousand DB calls in my app and fetching data from config file every time won't be a good option.